# Rasp pi 4B kali usb SSH

Tags: ssh, usb, raspberry-pi, kali-linux, openssh

Здрасьте, такая проблема нужен доступ к (подключаюсь с Android) SSH по USB к Kali который стоит на rasp pi 4B. Но инструкции которые нашёл в инете не работают, а доступ то нужен. Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не указали, что именно пробовали.
Предлагаю следующее:

```
sudo systemctl start ssh.socket - включить службу.
sudo systemctl enable ssh.socket - настроить автозапуск службы.
systemctl status ssh.socket - проверить статус службы.
```

Бывает такое, что `Kali` не принимает пароль, надо сделать:

найти файл `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`
найти в нём строку `#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password`
отредактировать на `PermitRootLogin yes`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41 https://gist.github.com/gbaman/975e2db164b3ca2b51ae11e45e8fd40a пробовал это + обычный доступ к SSH через wifi работает, а мне надо через USB

Comment: херь какая-то, интересно, и где Вы там увидели настройки доступа по SSH...

я так понимаю, Вы не можете получить доступ к граф. интерфейсу Kali физическим методом?

Comment: You can SSH into it using raspberrypi.local as the address. вот про SSH + я не могу получить доступ к терминалу

Comment: @Matthew, покажите что Вы указываете при подключении и какую ошибку Вам выдаёт. Спасибо.

Comment: 1 секунду пожалуйста

Comment: я нашел ошибку, она оказалась в неправильном хосте ( я указывал root@kali а надо root@hostname где hostname = вашему кастомному хосту если он у вас конечно кастомный) + стыдно признавать я допустил ошибку в файле cmdline.txt не поставил пробел

Comment: Спасибо вам за всё!

Comment: @Matthew, пожалуйста!

Comment: Извините не работает, это было разовое действие, после перезагрузке всё пропало, я также подключил телефон к RPI пытаюсь подключиться не выходит

Comment: @Matthew, всегда, когда сообщаете о проблеме, прикладывайте сообщение об ошибке и полное Ваше действие. Иначе, помочь Вам ну ни как нельзя.

Comment: Понял, зарублю на носу. А вот ошибка "ssh: Could not resolve hostname kali: No address associated with hostname"

Comment: перед подключением к какому-либо хосту по `IP-адресу`, убедитесь что он доступен командой `Ping` (для начала). Также, есть предположение, что в настройках сети `Kali` установлен параметр, который устанавливает `рандомный` `МАС-адрес`, и после каждой перезагрузки системы она будет получать новый `IP-адрес.` Смотрите в эту сторону. Возможно Ваша система, к который Вы подключаетесь - имеет новый `IP`

Comment: понял спасибо буду копать в эту сторону